# How to find(query) through a complex array for checking in IMongoCollection and LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code which uses `MongoDB` nuget packages and query MongoDb in C#. `_persons` is `IMongoCollection`. The query works and it returns the results. But `person.NameDetails.Name` array could have 1-2 array index and some array could be null. How do I refine the query to check if it is null, don't compare it and any array matches with the keywords, it will return without checking other arrays. Note: One person could have different set of firstname and surname because of it stores in different language also.

```
var documents = _persons.Find(person =>                 
    person.NameDetails.Name[0].NameValue.FirstName == firstName &&
    person.NameDetails.Name[0].NameValue.Surname == surname
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var documents = _persons.Find(person =>                 
    person.NameDetails.Name
        .Any(value => value.NameValue.FirstName == firstName && value.Surname == surname)
).ToList();
```